# Swift serial queue that only retains one pending task

Tags: swift, async-await, actor

I need a serial queue that instead of building up a backlog of tasks, only performs the task it's doing and the latest one queued since that started. Any job waiting in the queue for execution should be discarded if a new one comes in before it starts. Been trying to make it work using `actor`, `async` and `await` as follows but it's a bit advanced considering I only learned this stuff today. Is this close?

```
actor Worker {
    var task: Task <Void, Never>? = nil
    var next: Item? = nil
    var latestResult = false
    
    func analyseItem(_ item: Item) async -> Bool {
        // make our item next (but could be overwritten)
        next = item
        // let anything that's running complete
        await task?.value
        // start a task for the latest request
        task = Task {
            latestResult = next?.processItem()
            task = nil
        }
        return latestResult
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having with the above code?

Comment: I think if a few items are queued while one is ongoing, the `task = Task` line will fire multiple times leading to the same item being processed repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small project in `Playgrounds`

```
import Combine
import Foundation
import _Concurrency

actor Analyzer {
    var timestamp = Date()
    var flag = false
    
    func analyzeData(timestamp: Date) async throws {
        if flag { return }
        
        flag = true
        
        print("analyzing @\(timestamp)...")

        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 3_000_000_000)

        print("analyzing @\(timestamp) complete.")
        
        flag = false
    }
}

let analyzer = Analyzer()
var cancellable: AnyCancellable

cancellable = Timer.publish(every: 2, on: .main, in: .default)
        .autoconnect()
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .map({ output -> Date in
            Task {
                try? await analyzer.analyzeData(timestamp: output)
            }
            
            return output
        })
        .sink(receiveValue: { date in
            // print(date)
        })
```

Since `flag` is isolated, tasks will be analyzed every 4 seconds, because the timers fired every 2 and tasks last 3 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, this would be a good no-nonsense way of approximating it.

Comment: This will discard anything that comes in while a previous task is still running. But he wanted a solution that “only performs the task it's doing and the latest one queued since that started.”